# APK Launching, "Keep Stopping" Message and logcat error..? How to fix?

Tags: react-native

I apk launching after logcat show this error.

[image]

Comment: By the image, i would say you are missing wifi state premission

you can check for details here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following permissions have to be defined in the `manifest.xml` file when using wifi state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```